# Magento link to review form of bought product for email

Tags: magento, hyperlink, product, review

We're using Magento CE 1.8.1 and sending customers an email after buying a product. We ask them for an review and therefore they must go to the webshop, search for the product, write a review etc
This is not as friendly as we would like so we want to send our customers an email with the direct link to the review form of the product their bought in it.

I query the database for the product but where can I find or create the link to the review form of that product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the URL from the product page and use that as your guide.

http://www.yoursite.com/review/product/list/id/**PRODUCT_ID**/#review-form

Replace **PRODUCT_ID** with the entity id of the product like this:

http://www.yoursite.com/review/product/list/id/1/#review-form